# How to find the row and column index in Table Layout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Am created the table layout programmatically.I want to find out the row and column index of the table,when i click the view inside the table layout,but am not able to get a solution for this.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

**Coding**

```
private TableLayout createTableLayout(int rowCount, int columnCount,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sheetdetails) {

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    tableRowParams.width = 30;
    tableRowParams.height = 30;
    tableRowParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

    int img_id = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        // 3) create tableRow
        tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        for (int j= 0; j < columnCount; j++) {

            im = new ImageView(this);
            im.setImageResource(R.drawable.noseat1);
            for (int k=0;k<sheetdetails.size();k++){

                if(sheetdetails.get(k).get("Row").equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(i))&&sheetdetails.get(k).get("Col").equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(j))){
                    im.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(sheetdetails.get(k).get("seat_img")));
                    break;
                }

            }
            im.setTag(img_id);
            im.setOnClickListener(this);
            tableRow.addView(im, tableRowParams);
            img_id++;
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow,tableLayoutParams);
    }

    return tableLayout;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //here i want to display the row and column index like (0,0),(0,1)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via next approach:

add new class

```
public static class TableData{
    public final int RowIndex;
    public final int ColumnIndex;
    public final int ImageId;

    public TableData(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, int imageId) {
        RowIndex = rowIndex;
        ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
        ImageId = imageId;
    }
}
```

update your `createTableLayout`

```
im.setTag(new TableData(i, j, img_id));
```

update your `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TableData tableData = (TableData) v.getTag();
    if (null != tableData) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on " + tableData.RowIndex + ", " + tableData.ColumnIndex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```